# Procedure invocation failed: Read timed out

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am developing a MobileFirst Platform adapter. When i click on "Call MobileFirst Adapter" it gives me "Procedure invocation failed. Read timed out" error. Please see the complete log and let me know what is wrong

```
    [ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project         SecApp]MyRestAdapter1/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project SecApp]
    Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to Javatechig.com:80 [Javatechig.com/198.1.121.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project SecApp]org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to Javatechig.com:80 [Javatechig.com/198.1.121.188] failed: Connection timed out: connectjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to Javatechig.com:80 [Javatechig.com/198.1.121.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect
at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:271)
at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:201)
at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:185)
at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:155)
at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:141)
at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)
at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:676)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:622)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:69)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:504)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:501)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:579)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:563)
at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_12(/integration.js:103)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1473)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:107)
at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:267)
at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:241)
at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:211)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:125)
at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)
at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:676)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:622)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:69)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:504)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:501)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:155)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JSAdapterInvoker.invokeAdapter(JSAdapterInvoker.java:35)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JSAdapterRestWrapper.getFeeds1Get(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at com.worklight.wink.extensions.WorklightWinkHandler$1.run(WorklightWinkHandler.java:50)
at com.worklight.wink.extensions.WorklightWinkHandler$1.run(WorklightWinkHandler.java:45)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.accessTheResourceWithIdentity(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:98)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.access$000(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:38)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:84)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:81)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter$1.run(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:143)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter$1.run(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:134)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at com.worklight.oauth.validation.ValidationFilterHelper.filterRequest(ValidationFilterHelper.java:60)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter.securedAccessToResource(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:134)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthValidatorFilter.filterRequest(OAuthValidatorFilter.java:101)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.handleRequest(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:81)
at com.worklight.wink.extensions.WorklightWinkHandler.handleRequest(WorklightWinkHandler.java:45)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:255)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.RESTAdaptersServiceServlet.doService(RESTAdaptersServiceServlet.java:69)
at com.worklight.adapters.rest.RESTAdaptersServlet.service(RESTAdaptersServlet.java:64)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:766)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:472)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:74)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:975)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1097)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:938)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to Javatechig.com:80 [Javatechig.com/198.1.121.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:269)
... 129 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
... 138 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a timeout...

- Make sure you're attempting to connect to the correct address
- Try to increase the timeout specification for the procedure in the adapter XML file
- Make sure there is no firewall or alike in the way that prevents the connections or delays it
- You can also inspect the network traffic in Wireshark

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you tested the service in soapui and the backend is working within the timeout defined in adapter xml. The below could be the issue.

If you use the "Call MobileFirst Backend Service" that should work fine.

I was having the same issue. Looks like it's an issue with Mobilefirst client "Invoke MobileFirst Adapter". If you print the response in the adapter JS, you would notice that in that the Test client just gives up on the adapter printing Read timed out. But the adapter is still working and will print the response in a few seconds in the log. 
This clearly seems to be the issue with test client which is timing out and not the adapter itself.

```
var result =invokeWebService(request, headers, soapAction);
WL.Logger.warn(result);
```

Hope this helps. I wasted a whole day figuring this out. Oh well IBM. :)